# How to make a Premiere project save faster

Tags: premiere

I'm working on a big project. It's on a fast SSD.  All good..
But it's starting to take ages to save.
What do you do to speed this up?

- Ditch old edit versions?
- Unlink After Effects comps that you've rendered?
- consolidate and save as? (seems a bit drastic and might take forever... and does it still crash all the time?)
- something I haven't thought of?

What has the most effect on saving speed in your experience?